# Magento cron.php/cron.sh not working when executed through cPanel Cron Job

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

I tried these two commands from SSH. They worked.

```
/bin/sh /path/to/magento/cron.sh
/usr/bin/php /path/to/magento/cron.php
```

I put exactly the same commands (either one) on cPanel Cron Job. The commands were executed, but nothing happened. What might be wrong here?

Curl command works, but i'm trying to make **cron.php** not accessible from outside.

Comment: is there any error in `/var/spool/mail/{CPANELUSER}`  ? or add MAILTO="YOUR_MAIL_ADDRESS" on top of your crontab file

Comment: I set it up so that cPanel sends output to my mailbox every time the cron job runs. No errors.

Comment: How does your crontab look after you have configured it in Cpanel? `crontab -e`

Comment: Running "crontab -e" I got "/bin/sh: pico: command not found /usr/bin/crontab.cagefs: "pico" exited with status 127." Now I found out if I add options to the end, the cron job works! When running in SSH, I don't have to add options. Any idea why? Here are new cron commands: */5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/frcb/public_html/cron.php -mdefault
*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/frcb/public_html/cron.php -malways

Comment: @Shawn What do you mean by nothing happening and but i'm trying to make cron.php not accessible from outside. Can you explain bit more?

Answer (score 2):

You cron should look like the following path:-

By **SSH Server** use this,

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/curl --silent -H "Host: abc.com" http://localhost/cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

**Note:-** Here, the first part " ***/5 * * * *** " and " **10 * * * *** " are the CRON schedule times.

OR

```
10 * * * * /usr/bin/php /www/virtual/username/cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The command itself in this example has three parts:

1. "**/usr/bin/php**". PHP scripts usually are not executable by
   themselves. Therefore we need to run it through the PHP parser.
2. "**/www/virtual/username/cron.php**". This is just the path to the
   script.
3. "**> /dev/null 2>&1**". This part is handling the output of the script.
   More on this later.

Answer (score 0):

You cron should look like the following

```
* * * * * /bin/sh /path/to/your/site.com/html/cron.sh &> /dev/null
```

Comment: Yes that's what I have on cPanel Cron Job. Not working.

Comment: What does your hosting provider say? What is "Not" working?

Answer (score 0):

Please run `cron.php` using http://www.example.com/cron.php and check table `cron_schedule` in database and you could able to see new entries.

Then update command  - **/bin/sh /path/to/your/site/public_html/cron.sh >/dev/null 2>&1**

And check table `cron_schedule` in database and you could able to see new entries.

Answer (score 0):

Normally. If you run

/usr/bin/php /path/to/magento/cron.php

First: with no parameter. Cron.php will call:

- cron.sh -mdefault 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
- cron.sh -malways 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &

As you tell: /bin/sh: pico: command not found /usr/bin/crontab.cagefs
That is the reason it do nothing. I mean because sh shell have error it self.

Second: With parameter:
cron.php -mdefault or cron.php -malways. The call immediate executed at php side do not call cron.sh. So it is perfect fine in this case.